# How to fetch a single merged row which contains the filtered value from conditions applied on a driving column?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks, common-table-expression, window-functions

Consider the following table `person_details` which will be my input

| id | name | trust_on_name | age | trust_on_age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **John Doe** | 90 | null | null |
| 1 | john D. | 50 | **25** | 90 |
| 1 | null | 0 | twenties | 50 |

Here `null` represent actual null values. `trust*` columns can have integer values in multiples of 10 and `null` where I am using `COALESCE` function to replace such nulls with `0`.

I want to now form a single master row where `id` is the primary key column in my table. This is driven by the value on the trust of a particular column, here `trust_on_name` with the highest value will drive the value of `name` I will choose, so I will pick the highlighted values and form the final row as shown below as my output:

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 25 |

For this, I have tried using the following piece of logic which seems cumbersome and non-trivial:

```sql
WITH cte_name AS (
  SELECT id,
         `name` AS name,
         trust_on_name,
         null as `age`,
         trust_on_age
  FROM person_details
  QUALIFY trust_on_name = MAX(trust_on_name) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
),
cte_age AS (
  SELECT id,
         null as `name`,
         trust_on_name,
         age,
         trust_on_age
  FROM person_details
  QUALIFY trust_on_age = MAX(trust_on_age) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
)

SELECT 
    A.id,
    A.name,
    B.age
FROM cte_name A
INNER JOIN cte_age B
ON A.id = B.id
WHERE A.trust_on_name > COALESCE(B.trust_on_name, 0) AND B.trust_on_age > COALESCE(A.trust_on_age, 0)
```

Now, is there a better alternative to do this iteratively assuming we have lot of such columns in the table (i.e. `<column>`, `<trust_on_column>` pairs) and with this approach, I will have to create so many ctes per (`<column>`, `<trust_on_column>`) combination and do a join to identify that one record where as a whole is trusted !?

I have used Spark-SQL and Databricks to run and execute this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by / collect_list to perform this in a different way (group then lookup):

```scala
import sparkSession.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  ("1", "John Doe", "90", null, null),
  ("1", "john D.", "50", "25", "90"),
  ("1", null, "0", "twenties", "50")
).toDF("id","name","trust_on_name","age","trust_on_age")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("person_details")
sparkSession.sql(
"""
select id, element_at(name, cast(array_position(trust_on_name, array_max(trust_on_name)) as int)) name,
  element_at(age, cast(array_position(trust_on_age, array_max(trust_on_age)) as int)) age
 from (
  select id, collect_list(name) name, 
    collect_list(trust_on_name) trust_on_name, 
    collect_list(age) age, 
    collect_list(trust_on_age) trust_on_age 
  from person_details 
  group by id
  distribute by id
 )
"""
).show
```

The cast is needed as array_position returns bigint and element_at only accepts int.  Distribute by should be chosen appropriately but if the rows are all on a single partition and even after shuffle should be consistent.

If you can use scala instead of sql directly then you could generate the element_at stuff, or perhaps use [lambdas](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/advanced/userFunctions/) for that.

Comment: Thank you! This should do it. I have created some wrappers around the array functions you have suggested just to avoid repetitions now. It works faster than the join approach I have implemented.